# Cannot resolve GlideAnimation when added this in dependency implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

Tags: android, android-glide, google-places

I have this in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

   //getting conflict after adding this library
   implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
}
```

I don't know why I am getting this error `Cannot resolve com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation`  after adding place library from Google. When I remove this there is no issue.

Answer (score 7):

The solution was to add this:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   ...
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

   //exclude glide coming from place api
   implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'glide'
    }
}
```